# Anyone else having a problem clicking inside number inputs on newest Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, styling

Anyone else having this problem? Anyone got a work around?

On a number input, if you have padding or a width, you can't click between characters inside it, unless it's right aligned align.

Newest Chrome on Mac OS, version: 77.0.3865.90

Not happening in other browsers and I only updated Chrome recently and it's been happening since then.

Snippet below to test on.

```html
<p>
Try click between characters in the values of the broken one compared to the others.</p>

Input type text, works fine.<br>
<input type="text" value="hello123"><br><br>
Input type number, no styling, works fine.<br>
<input type="number" value="123456789"><br><br>
<b>Input type number with width/padding styling, broken.</b><br>
<input type="number" value="123456789" style="width:100px; padding:5px;"><br><br>
Input type number with width/padding styling but right align, works fine.<br>
<input type="number" value="123456789" style="width:100px; padding:5px; text-align:right;">
```

Comment: yes, same problem. chrome version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Did some more testing. It looks like the click itself works fine, but the click point is shifted right by the padding-left width.

Comment: @DenisO. Still get issues on my website with taking padding out and having a set width. Kind of got around it by giving a parent div the width and making the input 100% of it, then using text-index for the padding-left, doesn't feel like the right thing to do though just for this bug on a version of chrome.

Comment: @DenisO. Just installed the latest beta version (78.0.3904.34). Works how it should on that, so looks like they know about the problem.